# Java Coding and Constructors

Tags: java

I've recently started taking an intro java class(I apologize in advance for my lack of knowledge) and I've run into some trouble. I was required to make a program that contains 3 data fields, 2 constructors, and 4 methods.

I'm having a hell of a time trying to put some input into this, where the user would choose from 1 of the 3 data fields I made up for car prices and choose their vehicle. As far as the constructors go, I made a default one but I'm not sure on how to A) implement another constructor and B) how do I involve the input into this and C) where the methods go in that.

I'm thinking of putting the input first but that ruins my constructors?

I realize I asked a lot, but this is an online class without a text, and I'm basically starving for knowledge. I've included what I got so far below. Feedback is appreciated. Again, I apologize for the lack of knowledge but I'm trying --

```
public class Vehicle{
    int truck;
    int car;
    int van;

    public Vehicle(int t, int c, int v){
        truck=t;
        car=c;
        van=v;
    }
    public Vehicle(){
        truck=0;
        car=0;
        van=0;   
    }    
}
public static void main (String[] args) {
    Vehicle cost= new vehicle(25000,15000,22500);
    //*cost.truck=25000; cost.car=15000; cost.van=22500;*//
    Vehicle this Vehicle= new vehicle();
    Vehicle choice Vehicle= new vehicle(25000,22500);

    system.out.println("Default prices are 25000 for a truck, 15000 for a car, and"
                         + "22500 for a van, you chose" + 

}

}
```

Comment: Programming questions are off-topic at [cs.se] SE. For some pointers in the right direction, you should review your course materials and maybe find a good book to go with them (book recommendations aren't usually given anywhere on Stack Exchange because they're completely opinion-based). Your constructors are fine but your `main` method isn't in any class and you seem to have spaces in your variable names (`this Vehicle`), which is illegal. I can't actually work out what your program is trying to do, from your description or your code.

Answer (score 0):

Based from your question, you must be asking all about how to define classes and use them in general.

*Question A. How to implement another constructor?*

From your case, I see that you've already define your own constructor, but having problem to define another. To define another constructor, you have to know your parameters that 
would be passed.

Here, you have three arguments. (variable t, c, v).

```
public Vehicle(int t, int c, int v){
    truck=t;
    car=c;
    van=v;
}
```

Another, constructor with no arguments.

```
public Vehicle(){
    truck=0;
    car=0;
    van=0;   
}
```

When you define another constructor, you must not define another three arguments constructor of the same type, or another constructor with no arguments.

Therefore, you can have constructor method like this.

```
public Vehicle(int veh, int price){
    switch (veh) {
        case 0:
            truck = price;
        case ...
    }  
}
```

*Question B. How do I involve the input? Where to involve them in methods*

From your problem, this statement is already calling constructor, Which means, you are already involving an input to a class.

```
Vehicle cost = new Vehicle(25000,15000,22500);
```

Which is the same as calling a constructor with no arguments, and setting the current prices for the vehicles.

```
Vehicle choice = new Vehicle();
choice.truck = 25000;
choice.car = 22500;
```

Now, if you are thinking of is there another way to input datas through methods. It is called `Encapsulation`. To achieve this OOP concept, you should define data members as `Private`.

```
private int truck;
// public int truck; <- not like this.
```

Then, you can have involve input and probably output. Using the concept of getters and setters. In which you involve methods.

```
// simple setter
public void setTruckPrice(int t) {
    truck = t;
}

// simple getter
public int getTruckPrice(int t) {
   return truck;
}
```

P.S. i forgot to edit its encapsulation.

If you want more information, just refer to these links.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classes.html

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/index.htm

Comment: Your example of polymorphism has nothing to do with polymorphism. Polymorphism is the ability to treat multiple types (typically, subclasses of a specific given class) as if they were one type, and your code doesn't do this at all. What you're actually doing is data encapsulation (putting data into classes and only allowing methods inside the class to manipulate that data).

Comment: Also, providing arguments to a constructor isn't usually described as "input". Input usually means obtaining data from the user.